# Kafka Service Will Not Start

Tags: cmd, apache-kafka

I am using the following command to start the Kafka Service. When I hit enter a new command line prompt is created but nothing happens. I have zookeeper up and running. Kafka is located at `C:\kafka`

```
C:\kafka\.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

I have tried changing the service file as described below (using my directory instead of the example)

C. Setting Up Kafka
1. Go to your Kafka config directory. For me its `C:\kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0\config`

2. Edit the file `server.properties`
3. Find and edit the line `log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs` to `log.dir= C:\kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0\kafka-logs`
4. If your ZooKeeper is running on some other machine or cluster you can edit `zookeeper.connect:2181` to your custom IP and port. For this demo, we are using the same machine so there's no need to change. Also the Kafka port and broker.id are configurable in this file. Leave other settings as is.
5. Your Kafka will run on default port `9092` and connect to ZooKeeper’s default port, `2181`.

I would expect the kafka service to kickoff when I press enter instead a new command line opens. I get the same result if I type gibberish after the `.bat`

Comment: What do you mean by "a new command line prompt is created" ?

Comment: It does the same as if you click enter without any command. It goes down a row with a blank command line

Comment: Did you check your logs?

Comment: I have not. Do you have to enable logging first?

Comment: Inspect the logs, inspect the memory consumption. If Kafka is consuming too much it crash with no trace.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using such an old version of Kafka, but those commands work for me and don't create new prompt windows

Comment: Two questions, in which directory are you when you type your command? Why do say Kafka is in C:\kafka and also say config file is in C:\kafka_2.11....... ?